# Subselect in Oracle 12c with bad performance

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

After migration from Oracle 11g to 12c we have a massive performance issue for example with the following select statement. The same statement works fine in 11g.

**Table and Indexes**

```
-- Create table
create table PS_CS_ADRART_TB
(
  cs_adressmandant   VARCHAR2(5) not null,
  cs_person_id       VARCHAR2(20) not null,
  cs_beziehung_id    VARCHAR2(20) not null,
  seqnum             INTEGER not null,
  effdt              DATE,
  eff_status         VARCHAR2(1) not null,
  cs_adrart_cd       VARCHAR2(20) not null,
  cs_adress_id       VARCHAR2(20) not null,
  cs_kdnr_as400      VARCHAR2(8) not null,
  cs_plzgk           VARCHAR2(11) not null,
  cs_plz_pf          VARCHAR2(15) not null,
  cs_aendgr_cd       VARCHAR2(20) not null,
  cs_datasource_cd   VARCHAR2(20) not null,
  cs_betrag          NUMBER(14,4) not null,
  cs_belegdat        DATE,
  cs_adrtyp_xl       VARCHAR2(2) not null,
  cs_checked         VARCHAR2(1) not null,
  cs_journal_xl      VARCHAR2(4) not null,
  address2           VARCHAR2(55) not null,
  row_added_dttm     TIMESTAMP(6),
  row_added_oprid    VARCHAR2(30) not null,
  row_lastmant_dttm  TIMESTAMP(6),
  row_lastmant_oprid VARCHAR2(30) not null,
  cs_recstat_xl      VARCHAR2(4) not null,
  cs_update_count    NUMBER(10) not null
)
tablespace CS_APP
  pctfree 10
  initrans 1
  maxtrans 255
  storage
  (
    initial 102416K
    next 1M
    minextents 1
    maxextents unlimited
  );
-- Create/Recreate indexes 
create unique index PSACS_ADRART_TB on PS_CS_ADRART_TB (CS_ADRESSMANDANT, CS_KDNR_AS400, EFFDT)
  tablespace PSINDEX
  pctfree 10
  initrans 2
  maxtrans 255
  storage
  (
    initial 20M
    next 1M
    minextents 1
    maxextents unlimited
  );
create index PSBCS_ADRART_TB on PS_CS_ADRART_TB (CS_PERSON_ID)
  tablespace PSINDEX
  pctfree 10
  initrans 2
  maxtrans 255
  storage
  (
    initial 20M
    next 1M
    minextents 1
    maxextents unlimited
  );
create index PSCCS_ADRART_TB on PS_CS_ADRART_TB (CS_BEZIEHUNG_ID)
  tablespace PSINDEX
  pctfree 10
  initrans 2
  maxtrans 255
  storage
  (
    initial 20M
    next 1M
    minextents 1
    maxextents unlimited
  );
create unique index PS_CS_ADRART_TB on PS_CS_ADRART_TB (CS_ADRESSMANDANT, CS_PERSON_ID, CS_BEZIEHUNG_ID, SEQNUM, EFFDT)
  tablespace PSINDEX
  pctfree 10
  initrans 2
  maxtrans 255
  storage
  (
    initial 20M
    next 1M
    minextents 1
    maxextents unlimited
  );
create index PSDCS_ADRART_TB on PS_CS_ADRART_TB (CS_PLZ_PF)
  tablespace PSINDEX
  pctfree 10
  initrans 2
  maxtrans 255
  storage
  (
    initial 40K
    next 1M
    minextents 1
    maxextents unlimited
  );
create index PS0CS_ADRART_TB on PS_CS_ADRART_TB (CS_ADRESS_ID, CS_ADRESSMANDANT, CS_PERSON_ID, CS_BEZIEHUNG_ID, SEQNUM, EFFDT)
  tablespace PSINDEX
  pctfree 10
  initrans 2
  maxtrans 255
  storage
  (
    initial 20M
    next 1M
    minextents 1
    maxextents unlimited
  );
create index PS1CS_ADRART_TB on PS_CS_ADRART_TB (CS_KDNR_AS400, CS_ADRESSMANDANT, CS_PERSON_ID, CS_BEZIEHUNG_ID, SEQNUM, EFFDT)
  tablespace PSINDEX
  pctfree 10
  initrans 2
  maxtrans 255
  storage
  (
    initial 20M
    next 1M
    minextents 1
    maxextents unlimited
  );
create index PS2CS_ADRART_TB on PS_CS_ADRART_TB (ROW_ADDED_DTTM, CS_ADRESSMANDANT, CS_PERSON_ID, CS_BEZIEHUNG_ID, SEQNUM, EFFDT)
  tablespace PSINDEX
  pctfree 10
  initrans 2
  maxtrans 255
  storage
  (
    initial 40K
    next 1M
    minextents 1
    maxextents unlimited
  );
create index PS3CS_ADRART_TB on PS_CS_ADRART_TB (ROW_ADDED_OPRID, CS_ADRESSMANDANT, CS_PERSON_ID, CS_BEZIEHUNG_ID, SEQNUM, EFFDT)
  tablespace PSINDEX
  pctfree 10
  initrans 2
  maxtrans 255
  storage
  (
    initial 40K
    next 1M
    minextents 1
    maxextents unlimited
  );
create index PS4CS_ADRART_TB on PS_CS_ADRART_TB (ROW_LASTMANT_DTTM, CS_ADRESSMANDANT, CS_PERSON_ID, CS_BEZIEHUNG_ID, SEQNUM, EFFDT)
  tablespace PSINDEX
  pctfree 10
  initrans 2
  maxtrans 255
  storage
  (
    initial 40K
    next 1M
    minextents 1
    maxextents unlimited
  );
create index PS5CS_ADRART_TB on PS_CS_ADRART_TB (ROW_LASTMANT_OPRID, CS_ADRESSMANDANT, CS_PERSON_ID, CS_BEZIEHUNG_ID, SEQNUM, EFFDT)
  tablespace PSINDEX
  pctfree 10
  initrans 2
  maxtrans 255
  storage
  (
    initial 40K
    next 1M
    minextents 1
    maxextents unlimited
  );
create index PS6CS_ADRART_TB on PS_CS_ADRART_TB (CS_RECSTAT_XL, CS_ADRESSMANDANT, CS_PERSON_ID, CS_BEZIEHUNG_ID, SEQNUM, EFFDT)
  tablespace PSINDEX
  pctfree 10
  initrans 2
  maxtrans 255
  storage
  (
    initial 40K
    next 1M
    minextents 1
    maxextents unlimited
  );
```

**Table Size**

```
select count(*) from ps_cs_adrart_tb a 
--> 41367270
```

**Select Statement**

```
    SELECT A.CS_ADRESS_ID, A.SEQNUM, TO_CHAR(A.EFFDT, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
      from PS_CS_ADRART_TB A
    where A.CS_ADRESSMANDANT = '001'
       and a.cs_kdnr_as400 = '63916917'
       and a.effdt =
           (select max(b.effdt)
              from ps_cs_adrart_tb b
             where b.cs_adressmandant = a.cs_adressmandant 
               and b.cs_person_id = a.cs_person_id 
               and b.cs_beziehung_id = a.cs_beziehung_id
               and b.seqnum = a.seqnum
               and b.effdt  <= trunc(sysdate)
               )
```

**Explain Plan Oracle 11g**

```
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Id  | Operation                       | Name            | Rows | Bytes | Cost | Time     |
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                |                 |    1 |    89 |    2 | 00:00:01 |
    | * 1 |   FILTER                        |                 |      |       |      |          |
    |   2 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | PS_CS_ADRART_TB |    1 |    89 |    1 | 00:00:01 |
    | * 3 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN            | PSACS_ADRART_TB |    1 |       |    1 | 00:00:01 |
    |   4 |    SORT AGGREGATE               |                 |    1 |    59 |      |          |
    |   5 |     FIRST ROW                   |                 |    1 |    59 |    1 | 00:00:01 |
    | * 6 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN (MIN/MAX) | PS_CS_ADRART_TB |    1 |    59 |    1 | 00:00:01 |
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
    ------------------------------------------
    * 1 - filter("A"."EFFDT"= (SELECT MAX("B"."EFFDT") FROM "PS_CS_ADRART_TB" "B" WHERE "B"."EFFDT"<=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!) AND "B"."SEQNUM"=:B1 AND "B"."CS_BEZIEHUNG_ID"=:B2 AND "B"."CS_PERSON_ID"=:B3 AND
      "B"."CS_ADRESSMANDANT"=:B4))
    * 3 - access("A"."CS_ADRESSMANDANT"='001' AND "A"."CS_KDNR_AS400"='63916917')
    * 6 - access("B"."CS_ADRESSMANDANT"=:B1 AND "B"."CS_PERSON_ID"=:B2 AND "B"."CS_BEZIEHUNG_ID"=:B3 AND "B"."SEQNUM"=:B4 AND "B"."EFFDT"<=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!))
```

**Explain Plan Oracle 12c**

```
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Id  | Operation                              | Name            | Rows     | Bytes     | Cost  | Time     |
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                       |                 |        1 |       140 | 34366 | 00:00:02 |
    | * 1 |   HASH JOIN                            |                 |        1 |       140 | 34366 | 00:00:02 |
    |   2 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED | PS_CS_ADRART_TB |        1 |        89 |     1 | 00:00:01 |
    | * 3 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN                   | PS1CS_ADRART_TB |        1 |           |     1 | 00:00:01 |
    |   4 |    VIEW                                | VW_SQ_1         |    41889 |   2136339 | 34365 | 00:00:02 |
    | * 5 |     FILTER                             |                 |          |           |       |          |
    |   6 |      HASH GROUP BY                     |                 |    41889 |   2471451 | 34365 | 00:00:02 |
    | * 7 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN                 | PS_CS_ADRART_TB | 12746381 | 752036479 | 34365 | 00:00:02 |
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
    ------------------------------------------
    * 1 - access("A"."EFFDT"="MAX(B.EFFDT)" AND "ITEM_1"="A"."CS_ADRESSMANDANT" AND "ITEM_2"="A"."CS_PERSON_ID" AND "ITEM_3"="A"."CS_BEZIEHUNG_ID" AND "ITEM_4"="A"."SEQNUM")
    * 3 - access("A"."CS_KDNR_AS400"='63916917' AND "A"."CS_ADRESSMANDANT"='001')
    * 5 - filter('001'='001')
    * 7 - access("B"."CS_ADRESSMANDANT"='001' AND "B"."EFFDT"<=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!))
    * 7 - filter("B"."EFFDT"<=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!))


    Note
    -----
    - dynamic sampling used for this statement
```

As you can see, from the index `PS_CS_ADRART_TB` only `CS_ADRESSMANDANT` and `EFFDT` are used to filter the data and that is quite bad.

With the following slightly different select statements the index is used by Oracle 12c as expected to determine data of subselect.

**Changing where condition of outer select**

```
  SELECT  A.CS_ADRESS_ID, A.SEQNUM, TO_CHAR(A.EFFDT, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    from PS_CS_ADRART_TB A
  where a.cs_kdnr_as400 = '53916917' -- without CS_ADRESSMANDANT condition
     and a.effdt =
         (select  max(b.effdt)
            from ps_cs_adrart_tb b
           where b.cs_adressmandant = a.cs_adressmandant and 
                 b.cs_person_id = a.cs_person_id 
             and b.cs_beziehung_id = a.cs_beziehung_id 
             and b.seqnum = a.seqnum 
             and b.effdt <= trunc(sysdate)
             )

    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Id  | Operation                             | Name            | Rows | Bytes | Cost | Time     |
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                      |                 |    1 |    89 |    2 | 00:00:01 |
    |   1 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED | PS_CS_ADRART_TB |    1 |    89 |    1 | 00:00:01 |
    | * 2 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                   | PS1CS_ADRART_TB |    1 |       |    1 | 00:00:01 |
    |   3 |     SORT AGGREGATE                    |                 |    1 |    59 |      |          |
    |   4 |      FIRST ROW                        |                 |    1 |    59 |    1 | 00:00:01 |
    | * 5 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN (MIN/MAX)      | PS_CS_ADRART_TB |    1 |    59 |    1 | 00:00:01 |
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
    ------------------------------------------
    * 2 - access("A"."CS_KDNR_AS400"='53916917')
    * 2 - filter("A"."EFFDT"= (SELECT MAX("B"."EFFDT") FROM "PS_CS_ADRART_TB" "B" WHERE "B"."EFFDT"<=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!) AND "B"."SEQNUM"=:B1 AND "B"."CS_BEZIEHUNG_ID"=:B2 AND "B"."CS_PERSON_ID"=:B3 AND
      "B"."CS_ADRESSMANDANT"=:B4))
    * 5 - access("B"."CS_ADRESSMANDANT"=:B1 AND "B"."CS_PERSON_ID"=:B2 AND "B"."CS_BEZIEHUNG_ID"=:B3 AND "B"."SEQNUM"=:B4 AND "B"."EFFDT"<=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!))


    Note
    -----
    - dynamic sampling used for this statement
```

**Using `min()` instead of `max()` in the subselect**

```
    SELECT A.CS_ADRESS_ID, A.SEQNUM, TO_CHAR(A.EFFDT, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), a.cs_person_id 
      from PS_CS_ADRART_TB A
    where a.cs_kdnr_as400 = '63916917' and a.cs_adressmandant = '001'
       and a.effdt =
           (select  min(b.effdt)
              from ps_cs_adrart_tb b
             where b.cs_adressmandant = a.cs_adressmandant
               and b.cs_person_id = a.cs_person_id
               and b.cs_beziehung_id = a.cs_beziehung_id
               and b.seqnum = a.seqnum
               and b.effdt  <= sysdate
               );

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Id  | Operation                              | Name            | Rows | Bytes | Cost | Time     |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                       |                 |    1 |   109 |    2 | 00:00:01 |
    |   1 |   NESTED LOOPS                         |                 |    1 |   109 |    2 | 00:00:01 |
    |   2 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED | PS_CS_ADRART_TB |    1 |    89 |    1 | 00:00:01 |
    | * 3 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN                   | PS1CS_ADRART_TB |    1 |       |    1 | 00:00:01 |
    | * 4 |    VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE               | VW_SQ_1         |    1 |    20 |    1 | 00:00:01 |
    |   5 |     SORT GROUP BY                      |                 |    1 |    59 |    1 | 00:00:01 |
    | * 6 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | PS_CS_ADRART_TB |    1 |    59 |    1 | 00:00:01 |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
    ------------------------------------------
    * 3 - access("A"."CS_KDNR_AS400"='63916917' AND "A"."CS_ADRESSMANDANT"='001')
    * 4 - filter("A"."EFFDT"="MIN(B.EFFDT)" AND "ITEM_1"="A"."CS_ADRESSMANDANT")
    * 6 - access("B"."CS_ADRESSMANDANT"='001' AND "B"."CS_PERSON_ID"="A"."CS_PERSON_ID" AND "B"."CS_BEZIEHUNG_ID"="A"."CS_BEZIEHUNG_ID" AND "B"."SEQNUM"="A"."SEQNUM" AND "B"."EFFDT"<=SYSDATE@!)


    Note
    -----
    - dynamic sampling used for this statement
```

Rebuilding indexes (as described above) and updating statistics by

```
EXEC DBMS_STATS.delete_table_stats('SYSADM', 'PS_CS_ADRART_TB');
-- EXEC DBMS_STATS.gather_table_stats('SYSADM', 'PS_CS_ADRART_TB');
EXEC DBMS_STATS.gather_table_stats(ownname => 'SYSADM', tabname =>  'PS_CS_ADRART_TB', cascade => true );
```

doesn't help.

What is going on here? Any advice is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please let me know why you down vote the question.

Comment: The question is clear, well tagged, contains all the statements to build the needed structures, gives informations on the size of the tables, contains many attempts and the plan for each statement... I can't figure what else should this kind of question contain... +1

Comment: The "*dynamic sampling used for this statement* in the 12c plan seems to indicate that the statistics are not up-to-date despite the `gather_table_stats()`. Does this change if you call `gather_table_stats()` with `cascade => true`? (And to rule out the obvious: is SYSADM really the _owner_ of those tables?)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name We called `DBMS_STATS.gather_table_stats` with option `cascade => true` with the same result. And yes, `SYSADM` is the owner of the table. The database is an upgraded copy of our Oracle 11g database.

Comment: What is the value of the parameter OPTIMIZER_DYNAMIC_SAMPLING in both databases?

Comment: @RobvanWijk OPTIMIZER_DYNAMIC_SAMPLING is at Level 4 on both databases.

Comment: Does the 12c plan change when you hint the query to not use dynamic sampling?

Comment: @RobvanWijk No, the plan doesn't change if dynamic sampling is disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should set the Parameter `_unnest_subquery` to `FALSE`.

You can try it with

```
alter session set "_unnest_subquery" = FALSE;
```

Comment: That's it! Oracle support recommends setting the hidden parameter _unnest_subquery to FALSE to improve the performance of PeopleSoft applications on Oracle databases. It's the same behaviour as described at http://www.bobbydurrettdba.com/2012/11/07/_unnest_subqueryfalse-for-peoplesoft-performance/

Answer (score 0):

Frank. As I understand you want to get one last row by any cs_person_id and cs_beziehung_id where b.effdt lower or equal than today.  First of all you may gather statistic with information about selectivity. It helps CBO to make choice.

```
BEGIN 
 dbms_stats.Gather_table_stats('SYSADM', 'PS_CS_ADRART_TB',
 method_opt => 'FOR COLUMNS SIZE 254 CS_KDNR_AS400 CS_ADRESSMANDANT'); 
END; 
/
```

Anothr one think what I find. You have a lot of indexes witch might be created as unique. It already contain unique index columns.

```
create unique index PS1CS_ADRART_TB on PS_CS_ADRART_TB (CS_KDNR_AS400, CS_ADRESSMANDANT, CS_PERSON_ID, CS_BEZIEHUNG_ID, SEQNUM, EFFDT)  ;
create unique index PS0CS_ADRART_TB on PS_CS_ADRART_TB (CS_ADRESS_ID, CS_ADRESSMANDANT, CS_PERSON_ID, CS_BEZIEHUNG_ID, SEQNUM, EFFDT);
create unique index PS1CS_ADRART_TB on PS_CS_ADRART_TB (CS_KDNR_AS400, CS_ADRESSMANDANT, CS_PERSON_ID, CS_BEZIEHUNG_ID, SEQNUM, EFFDT);
create unique index PS2CS_ADRART_TB on PS_CS_ADRART_TB (ROW_ADDED_DTTM, CS_ADRESSMANDANT, CS_PERSON_ID, CS_BEZIEHUNG_ID, SEQNUM, EFFDT);
create unique index PS3CS_ADRART_TB on PS_CS_ADRART_TB (ROW_ADDED_OPRID, CS_ADRESSMANDANT, CS_PERSON_ID, CS_BEZIEHUNG_ID, SEQNUM, EFFDT);
create unique index PS4CS_ADRART_TB on PS_CS_ADRART_TB (ROW_LASTMANT_DTTM, CS_ADRESSMANDANT, CS_PERSON_ID, CS_BEZIEHUNG_ID, SEQNUM, EFFDT);
create unique index PS5CS_ADRART_TB on PS_CS_ADRART_TB (ROW_LASTMANT_OPRID, CS_ADRESSMANDANT, CS_PERSON_ID, CS_BEZIEHUNG_ID, SEQNUM, EFFDT);
create unique index PS6CS_ADRART_TB on PS_CS_ADRART_TB (CS_RECSTAT_XL, CS_ADRESSMANDANT, CS_PERSON_ID, CS_BEZIEHUNG_ID, SEQNUM, EFFDT);
```

And at the end I try to rewrite query to exclude subquery

```
SELECT cs_adress_id,seqnum, effdt_chr 
FROM   (SELECT /* */ a.cs_adress_id 
          ,a.seqnum 
          ,to_char(a.effdt, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS effdt_chr 
          ,dense_rank() over(PARTITION BY a.cs_adressmandant, a.cs_person_id
                                        , a.cs_beziehung_id, a.seqnum 
                                 ORDER BY a.effdt DESC) AS  rnk 
    FROM   ps_cs_adrart_tb a 
    WHERE  a.cs_adressmandant = '001' 
      AND  a.cs_kdnr_as400 = '63916917' 
      AND  a.effdt <= trunc(sysdate) 
) 
WHERE  rnk = 1;
```

Comment: Yes, the statement selects the current data for the given person. The statistic values in the explain plan are up to date (12746381 rows for CS_ADRESSMANDANT=001 and EFFDT=sysdate is an adequate value), therefore the question is why the further fields CS_PERSON_ID, CS_BEZIEHUNG_ID and SEQNUM of this index are not used. And yes, we could change select statement or indexes, but we try to minimize changes of our application to avoid effort and risk by side effects.

Comment: Nevertheless I've tried it with `method_opt => 'FOR COLUMNS SIZE 254 CS_KDNR_AS400 CS_ADRESSMANDANT'` - but without success.

Comment: Its look like an Issue with hash_group_by. Could you please check plan query with  hint `/*+ opt_param('_optimizer_aggr_groupby_elim', 'true')*/`?

Comment: This hint doesn't affect the execution plan at all.